Zephyr Hello_World on ESP32C6 DevkitC
I am trying to build up some knowledge on Zephyr RTOS through some practical experience...unfortunately it is not going well.
I followed Zephyr's Getting Started Guide for setting up the dev environment. I then followed the board specific instructions for the board I am using, the ESP32C6_DevkitC, for building and flashing Zephyr's sample hello world program. My program successfully builds and I don't get any errors when I flash it onto the board.
However, when I view the serial monitor using west espressif monitor, I don't see the correct output. An excerpt of my output can be seen below.

As can be seen, the cnonection is successfully made to my devices serial monitor. However, no Zephyr output is being printed. There should be the following lines visible after the output I have
***** Booting Zephyr OS vx.x.x-xxx-gxxxxxxxxxxxx *****
Hello World! esp32c6_devkitc

I have double checked that the baud rate in the device tree (115200) is the same baud rate being used by the serial monitor
If anyone has any suggestions or pointers, I really would appreciate assistance. I have poured over the Zephyr documentation, any community posts asking for help, I have tried non-Zephyr tutorials for building and flashing this project but it all leads to the same result.
Edit: Just repeated everthing I did previously except built the program using -b esp_devkitc_wroom and then fkashed it onto a ESP-WROOM-32D board and I am now getting the correct output. Any ideas why this would be the case?
